# How to sort column with month order and calculate differences between column R data.table

Tags: r, sorting

**Goal :**
Sort column as month order 1~12 in a pivot table to get figures difference compare with different year same month .

**Desire data shape :**

```
# 1 - sort as every Jan ~ Dec inside every year 
setcolorder(d_c,
            c("2016-1","2017-1","2018-1".....))
# 2 - finally add column to calculate the differences
d_c[,"dif":=format(`lastyear_samemonth_column`-`neweryear_samemonthcolumn`,big.mark = ",")]
```

**Data :**

```
set.seed(566684)
n = 100
d <-as.data.table(tibble(month = sample(1:12, n, replace = TRUE),
                year   = sample(2016:2018,n, replace = TRUE),
                `year-month`   = paste(year, month, sep = '-'),
                value  = rnorm(n),
                c1 = sample(LETTERS,n,replace = TRUE)))
           
d_c <- dcast(d,c1 ~ `year-month`, value.var = "value" ,fun.aggregate = sum)
```

**Problem :**
They grouped by "year-month" column as ascending order but donnot how to sort as monthly order and assign dynamic column name to get the comparison result

Comment: Ronak , sorry for a lot of lacking information , I re-edited as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order the data you can use -

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c(1, order(as.numeric(sub('.*-', '', names(d_c)[-1]))) + 1)

d_c[, ..cols]
```

Comment: Ronak appreciated for your answer . Do you know why e.g. "2016-1" converted by sub(".*-","") become 1 or 10 e.t.c. but not "20161" ? What is the computing reason behind that ?

Comment: Since you want all the month columns together (meaning first all January columns, then February and so on) we are only extracting the month value i.e 1 from 2016-1 etc. `sub('.*-', ''...)` removes everything until `-`.

Comment: understand , I omitted the meaning of "remove until" regex. Thanyou